# DecimalFormat vs String.format

Tags: java, decimalformat

Am I missing something here? According to the doc, String.format "f" use HALF_UP rounding algorithm. So shouldn't the following two print the same result?

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.0");
double num = 3.55;
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
System.out.println(df.format(num));             // prints "3.5"
System.out.println(String.format("%.1f", num)); // prints "3.6"
```

Comment: `double num = 3.55` is already inexact, possibly something like `3.549999999999`. Not `DecimalFormatter`'s fault.

Comment: would love to hear more in depth explanation. e.g 1.55 would result 1.6, not 1.5. Also according to documentation String.format use HALF_UP, so my setting rounding mode of DecimalFormat to HALF_UP, shouldn't they produce the same result? This is also from the doc of HALF_UP "Note that this is the rounding mode that most of us were taught in grade school".

Comment: there is a deep explanation about double precision https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985

Comment: @EJP I realised that my question wasn't very clear, so I've rephrased it. So now this is more about how two different api treat double than how double is represented in binary.

Comment: I don't see the question answered in said duplicate.